# How to specify a username in ldapsearch tool?

Tags: ldap, command-line-interface

I'm new to ldap. I need to specify username in plaintext with some parameter without any sasl.

So this command gonna give you some search results, but it always empty cause there's no authorization:

```
ldapsearch -h 1.1.1.1 -p 389 -D "OU=SysAcc,OU=Infra,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -b "OU=blg,dc=whatever,dc=whatever2,dc=com"
```

I've found that I can add `-w mypasswd` to specify password, where can I specify a username? I started with `ldapsearch` because I'm having hard time to configure LDAP in one of web application I'm trying to setup. Just wanna check if my parameters are correct with `ldapsearch` tool, but I can't find how to specify username.

**EDIT:**

as from answer above just wanna write a final command how it should be:

```
   ldapsearch -h 1.1.1.1 -p 389 -W -D "CN=sysMYUSER,OU=SysAcc,OU=Infra,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -b "OU=blg,dc=whatever,dc=whatever2,dc=com"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `-D` option is the LDAP username-equivalent. It's the BindDN, which is the account you're trying to authenticate against with the password you supply either with `-w` or when prompted. You probably also want to use the `-x` option for a simple bind, since you're using a BindDN/password pair instead of SASL authentication.

Comment: I was completely confused about `bind_dn` purpose. I thought  it's just a 'path' where my user lies, and base is a path where I should search for user I specify. `bind_dn` is a user itself, together with path. thanks.

Comment: Yes, the BindDN is the "user". The BaseDN is the starting point for your search - it won't search anything that isn't below that point in the tree.